# Filter GridView Data using DataView for DateRange

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataview

Inside my Grid View I'm displaying some records including a Date Column which is in **dd-MMM-yyyy** format. I've two textboxes for the date range, which is used to filter the GridView using DataView.

The code that I've already tried

```
dv.RowFilter = "docket_date IN (#" + FromDate + "#, #" + ToDate + "#)";
```

this code returns **docket_date IN (#01-Sep-2018#, #15-Sep-2018#)** but no data is get selected for this range

I've tried this also

```
dv.RowFilter = "#" + FromDate + "# >= docket_date OR docket_date <= #" + ToDate + "#";
```

this code returns **#01-Sep-2018# >= docket_date OR docket_date <= #15-Sep-2018#** as result but no data is get selected for this range

**Note:** I'm using MySql as Database

Inside my gridview I've data for this date range but my filter query is not working

Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks

Comment: `dv.RowFilter = "docket_date IN (#" + FromDate + "#, #" + ToDate + "#)";` this one not going to select range, only selecting the given 2 dates values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a standard ISO format datetime like this (for 01-Sep-2018):

```
docket_date >= #2018-09-01# AND docket_date <= #2018-09-15#
```

There's a quick reference [here](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date)

Comment: Thank you for your response @Baskar, I've changed the format of the date but display the same result. In between the range of 2018-09-01 and 2018-09-15, it includes the record of 2018-08-23 also. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rohit_Chiki hope your field in datetime type? in that case it should work in the criteria.

Comment: You must use AND when you need between the 2 dates

Comment: as you've suggested I've used AND but now it displays only two results and that too of date 2018-08-23.

Comment: check my edited answer. criteria for between dates must be like this `docket_date >= #2018-09-01# AND docket_date <= #2018-09-15#`